# Change php reference when checkbox is clicked

Tags: php, html, checkbox, svg

I have an embedded SVG file which I use for SVG icon sprites. Additionally there is a HTML checkbox. If it's clicked I want to change the reference of the embedded SVG file to a different one. 
I use following phrase to include the SVG file in my HTML file:

```
  <?php include_once("processed/svg-defs.svg"); ?>
```

Now I'm searching for a way to change the file with jQuery when the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: Can You post your code here?

Comment: Should be visible now.

Comment: You mean to say you want to change the `include_once("processed/svg-defs.svg");` this file name Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

**index.php**

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['file'])){
        if($_REQUEST['file']==2){
        include_once("processed/svg-defs2.svg");    
        }else{
        include_once("processed/svg-defs.svg"); 
        }
    }
    ?>

   <input type="checkbox" onclick="window.location.href='file.php?file=<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['file']) && $_REQUEST['file']!='')?'':'2'?>'" <?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['file']) && $_REQUEST['file']!='')?'checked':''?>/>
```

Comment: Will it change back to the first image when I unclick the checkbox?

Comment: Yes, It will change back to the first image .

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately I can not get it right. I've used http://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/ and the php part is not working